# Why can't I assign a second controller in PES 2016 multiplayer?

Tags: xbox-one, pro-evolution-soccer-2016

I try to play PES 2016 on Xbox one as multiplayer on the same console, but when I go to select a team only one controller appears.

When we push 'A' on the other controller, the console switches control to the other controller

I've tried searching the internet for videos/posts but there is nothing on this issue at all.

Comment: Why are there  pes 2011 and pes 2015 tags?

Comment: i thinks it will be the same :)